# На какой кодировке писать программы?

Tags: javascript, java, кодировка

Какую кодировку выбирать для корпоративных приложений? Как для серверной части, так и для клиентской. В чем отличие, если я буду писать программу (серверная - Java, клиентская - JavaScript) на кодировке UTF-8, или на Windows-1251? К чему может привести ситуация, когда серверная и клиентская части, написаны в разных кодировках? Ну и, на какой кодировке, собственно, лучше писать программы. И, если некоторые пишут на Windows-1251, то чем она лучше, чем UTF-8?

Comment: Я бы лично убивал людей, которые строчат на джаве в виндовой кодировки, преступление против самой идеалогии языка.

Comment: Ну преимущество cp1251 простое: каждый символ -- один байт. Недостаток -- в один байт много не влезет. В utf-8 можно представить любой юникодный символ, но. Чтобы найти n-ный символ в строке, её надо просматривать. И длина файла может быть больше (максимум -- в два раза для кириллицы).

Comment: @system29a , пожалуйста, изложите в ответе ваш взгляд на эту проблему. Интересно узнать ваше мнение. Вполне возможно, что оно окажется очень полезным :)

Comment: @alexlz, разве на 50KB или на 10MB больше размер файла - имеет большое значение?

Comment: @Антон Мухин А кто в соседнем ответе писал про трафик?

Comment: Вопрос решен. Спасибо всем!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Всегда и везде выбирайте одинаковую кодировку для всех файлов, лучше всего UTF-8.
Для PHP давным давно есть расширение MB_String позволяющее работать с юникод-строками.
Java и Javascript стандартно работают с utf-8. Windows тоже давным давно корректно работает с UTF-8.

Используют Windows-1251 если:

1. Если проект старый.
2. Надеются экономить на трафике.

Comment: Хм! Какой убедительный ответ, спасибо! Подождем еще @system29a , что он думает.

Comment: 2 причина при нынешних скоростях почти неактуальна. Поэтому только если унаследованный код. В Windows Unicode на уровне ядра используется уже более 10 лет (только не UTF8, а UTF-16LE), на уровне пользовательских приложений национальные кодировки поддерживаются до сих пор только для того, чтобы не ломать совместимость. В Linux на этот шаг решились, какое-то время где-то в 2004-2006 годах было много веселья :) Потом все устаканилось.

Comment: Насчет "корректно работает" не совсем соглашусь, отвечал [тут](http://hashcode.ru/questions/89981/ошибка-hello-go-1-1-illegal-character-u-feff)

Answer (score 5):

Моё субъективное мнение — все мизерные преимущества cp1251 не могут конкурировать с её главными недостатками — сомнительной переносимостью и невозможным i18n. Именно поэтому Java, как язык, главной задачей которого является обеспечение переносимости и того, что ваше приложение работает везде одинаково, использует UTF-8.

Ваше приложение будет разумно вести себя только при использовании из России, где у всех стоит Windows и cp1251. Если же вам вдруг придётся выйти на более широкую аудиторию (или, например, кто-то будет пользоваться вашими приложениями из под мака, линукса или смартфона на андроиде), то, возможно, вы столкнётесь с неприятными спецэффектами.

Разные кодировки на серверной и клиентской части гарантируют вам пачку весёлых багов как минимум. Тут уж точно вам никто не мешает прийти к единообразию.

Answer (score 1):

1251 лучше тем, что с ней корректно работают строковые функции PHP без мультибайтового расширения. 
Не лучше. "Проще, доступнее"(С) Магистр Йода.

В модели с разделенными данными и логикой вы можете писать в любой кодировке, главное, точно знать кодировку данных: сама программа во всех кодировках будет выглядеть одинаково.
Если у вас встречаются нелатинские символы и в серверной части и в клиентской, самое плохое - будут зюки. Этого можно избежать, если вовремя сделать приведение кодировки. (Стоит ли рассказывать, что необходимо переводить ТОЛЬКО из менее мощной кодировки в более мощную?)

Для корпоративных приложений выбирайте 1251, если у всех винда: мороки будет меньше. 
Для всех остальных предпочтительнее utf

Comment: Интересно, какая же морока может возникнуть, если у всех винда?

Comment: Если винда - с win1251 никакой. =) Только, собственно, реализация задуманного.

Comment: Java по умолчанию работает с Unicode. К чему ее насиловать заставляя работать с cp1251 ?  
Про javascript ничего не скажу. cp1251 в веб-приложениях это древний век.

Comment: Извините, а разве в java по умолчанию не ucs-2, как в виндах? Имеется в виду юникод.

Comment: Поправлю, UCS-2 в Windows использовалась, только до Windows 2000, начиная с Windows 2000 используется UTF-16LE. В Java да - UCS-2.

Comment: Учитывая, что по дефолту в консоли русифицированной Windows используется CP866, а графический интерфейс работает с CP1251, то веселья всё равно хватает. И да, а если пользователи "корпоративного приложения" говорят не только на русском и английском?

Моя точка зрения - UTF-8 всегда и везде.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в Java сейчас тоже в char UTF-16LE. Для русских букв она совпадает с ucs-2.

Comment: @avp, да, точно, проверил [в официальном источнике](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/intl/faq.jsp#core-encoding) - UTF-16. Значит, они тоже отказались от раннего UCS-2.

В тему вопроса цитата из того же источника:

> Where circumstances permit, UTF-8 is an excellent character encoding.

Comment: А чем ещё можно было заменить ucs-2 без перекодирования существующих данных...

Comment: Да, еще раз все рубануть (это когда с самого начала ввели 2-х байтовые символы в Java) и перейти на UCS-4 не решились. Загнали проблему с несовсем корректными программами вглубь. С широко распространенными алфавитами ее не видно.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ сильно зависит от целевой платформы. UTF-8 конечно хорош, но если прожект под J2ME - он не покатит, поскольку там целевая кодировка ISO-8859-1.

Кроме того, я уже сталкивался со случаями когда народ хочет иметь русские идентификаторы (да-да, есть такие фрукты - которых надо расстреливать, но они все равно есть, причем в серьезной отрасли - нашей оборонке, там это стандарт де-факто), и там народ активно юзает CP1251, а то и CP866. С этим можно не соглашаться, но это факт.

P.S. При всех прочих, я естественно как нормальный джавер насколько возможно всегда стараюсь применить UTF-8