# Неверная кодировка сервлета

Tags: java, кодировка, servlet

С формы вызываю сервлет и пытаюсь вывести строчку. Вот код.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("привет");
}
```

Выводит кракозябры, в чем причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, тут грубая ошибка: ты забыл закрыть поток.

```
out.close();
```

Во вторых, для отсутствия всяких там плохих вещей, надо чтобы кодировка проекта была в `UTF-8`. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/91603/javascript-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B) было обсуждение по этому поводу. Далее посмотри что у тебя на html-страничке. Должно быть примерно так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
.... ... .. ..
```

Обрати внимание на `<meta charset="utf-8" />`. Может этого не хватает. Всех моих советов достаточно для того, чтобы все сработало в отношении кодировки как надо.

**UPD1**:
Да, идея еще подоспела. Тут у тебя выводится только строка "привет" на страничку, абсолютно без ничего. Скорее всего, все приходит в верной кодировке, потому что были бы знаки вопроса вместо кракозябр скорее всего. Значит в твоем браузере стоит по умолчанию кодировка винды и он не смог распознать что это кодировка UTF-8. Ведь приходит-то только одна строка на русском. Тут уж ничего удивительного. Уверен, если ты еще в поток запишешь все что необходимо для полноценной интернет странички с указанием кодировки, все будет работать более чем правильно всегда.